# Finding the line number of specific values in pandas dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a school project and I am trying to simulate a library's catalogue system. I have .csv files that hold all the data I need but I am having a problem with checking if an inputted title, author, bar code, etc. is in the data set. I have searched around for quite a while trying different solutions but nothing is working.
The idea that I have right now is that if I can find at what line the inputted data, then I can use .loc[] to get the needed info.
Is this the right track? is there another, more efficient way to do this?

```
import pandas
mainData = pandas.read_csv("mainData.csv")
barcodes = mainData["Barcode"]
authors = mainData["Author"]
titles = mainData["Title/Subtitle"]
callNumbers = mainData["Call Number"]
k = "Han, Jenny,"
for i in authors:
    if k == i:
        print("Success")
        k = authors.index[k]
        print(authors[k])
else:
    print("Fail" + k)
#    Please Note: This code only checks for an author match and has all other fields left out as I thought this code was too inefficient to add the rest of the fields. The code also does not find the line on witch the matched are located, therefore .loc[] can not be used to print out all the data found.
```

This is the code I am using right now, It outputs the result along with an error `` Python IndexError: only integers, slices (\`:\`), ellipsis (\`\...\`), numpy.newaxis (\`None\`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices `` and is very slow. I would like the code to be able to output the books and their respective info. I have found the the .loc[] feature (mentioned above) outputs the info quite nicely. [Here is the data I am using](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jDLfMKNS2cx17OGHs6Qa17LzlZwZngNJLm_PayHv_lg/edit?usp=sharing) .

*Edit:* I have been able to reduce the time it takes for the program to run and made a functional "prototype"

```
authorFirst = authorFirst.lower()
authorFirst = authorFirst.title()
authorFirst += ","
authorSecond = input("Enter author's last name: ")
authorSecond = authorSecond.lower()
authorSecond = authorSecond.title()
authorSecond += ", "

authorInput = authorSecond + authorFirst

print(mainData[mainData["Author"].isin([authorInput])])

bookChoice = input("Please Enter the number to the left of the barcode to select a book: ")
print(mainData.loc[int(bookChoice)])
```

id provides the functionality that I am looking for but I feel that there has to be a better way of doing it. (Not asking the user to input the row number). Idk if this is possible tho.

I am new to python and this is my first time using pandas so i'm sorry if this is  really shitty and hurts your brain.

Thank-you so much for your time!

Comment: Hi please include a sample of your data, along with the code you have tried. Also what is your expected output?

Comment: Ok, Will add that now

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question or title. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Ok ^ Really sorry, I thought my question had been answered but It turned out after further testing it was not, I will not add "Solved" to the title. Again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does not really need to find the numeric index of something, to do indexing.

Since you have not provided any starting point or data, I'll just provide a few pointers here as there are mans ways to [match and index things in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing).

```py
import pandas as pd

# build a library
library = pd.DataFrame({
    "Author": ["H.G. Wells", "Hubert Selby Jr.", "Ken Kesey"],
    "Title": [
        "The War of the Worlds",
        "Requiem for a Dream",
        "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest",
        ],
    "Published": [1898, 1979, 1962],
})

# find on some characteristics
mask_wells = library.Author.str.contains("Wells")
mask_rfad = library["Title"] == "Requiem for a Dream"
mask_xixth = library["Published"] < 1900
```